# Как GestureDetector получает LongPress событие?

Tags: android, gestures

Есть [вот](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-recyclerview-implementing-single-item-click-and-long-press-part-ii-b43ef8cb6ad8) такая статья в которой описано, как получить короткий и длинный клик.

Для этого используется `GestureDetector` и это работает

Вопрос - каким образом ни к чему не привязанный `GestureDetector` получает длинный клик?

Comment: я вот документацию читаю, и посмею допустить что данные приходят с сенсоров, или вопрос не об этом?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko то есть вы имеете ввиду, что я могу где угодно в проекте создать обьект `GestureDetector` ни к чему его не привязывая и получать ивенты? В целом я это предположил и попробовал в своем `RecyclerView` определил переменную и инициализировал ее в конструкторе , но почему то ничего не происходит при нажатии... Хотя у автора статьи по сути сделано то же самое, только не в `RecyclerView` , а в его лисенере и у него это как то работает...

Comment: да, я это и хотел сказать, вы можете в любом месте считать как длинные так и короткие нажатия (это мое мнение если что) :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko тогда почему когда я создаю его в `RecyclerView` то это не работает?

Comment: чисто гипотетически в `RecyclerView` есть свои методы для считывания не только одиночных нажатий но и длительных

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko сорри я хотел сказать в адаптере...

Comment: ну в адаптере тем более, там через holder.itemView можно считывать длинное нажатие

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, вы просто не заметили, что в тач-листенере вызывается `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)` - то есть все тач-события из листенера передаются детектору и он по ним определяет жесты и клики.